# views inside GridView becomes too small like single line

Tags: android, android-layout

my xml look like this. I have LinearLayout inside HorizontalScrollView and that LinearLayout has two GridView. In below code com.muvee.vea.view.GridViewFrame is the class which extends GridView so that i can set its widht according to its parents scrollview's width.But the views which are coming inside GridView are becoming very small like one line.  can any one suggest what should i do ?  The widht and height of gird view are  fine but the child wehich is inside it coming very small in one line.

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.7" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <com.muvee.vea.view.GridViewFrame
                    android:id="@+id/grid_add_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="15dip"
                    android:background="#800000"
                    android:numColumns="4"
                    android:padding="30dip"
                    android:verticalSpacing="15dip" >
                </com.muvee.vea.view.GridViewFrame>

                <com.muvee.vea.view.GridViewFrame
                    android:id="@+id/grid_add_video"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="15dip"
                    android:numColumns="4"
                    android:padding="30dip"
                    android:background="#FFA500"
                    android:verticalSpacing="15dip" >
                </com.muvee.vea.view.GridViewFrame>
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

[image: Screenshot Of Problem]

Comment: can you please post the problem screen shot?

Comment: HI paresh, Thanks for your reply. i have uploaded screenshot. please check.

Comment: thats the better to understand your problem exactly. :)

Comment: Ya. one picture is equals to 100 words. So can you suggest something.